# Difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable

I would like to know the difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file from eclipse with the runnable jar file creation.

If my program (runnable jar) uses other classes which require these external libraries(jars), what should I pick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between runnable jar library handling options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302894/what-is-the-difference-between-runnable-jar-library-handling-options)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want to put jars into your generated jar file, you can use packaging method.
For example if you are using an Apache library or some other 3rd party jars, you may want to keep these jars preserved in your generated jar. In this case, use packaging. 
*"Packaging required libraries into a jar file"* option puts classes of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader` package into your generated file and this package is just under the root directory of the generated jar file. This option also creates a larger jar file in terms of size due to jar loader classes of Eclipse.

Extracting required libraries will result in putting classes of 3rd party libraries into your jar file by following the package naming convention, e.g. if you open your jar content you can see some classes under `org.apache..` packages.

Main class entries are different between the `MANIFEST.MF` files of these jar files:

Main class entry when you **package** required libraries:

```
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Main class entry when you **extract** required libraries:

```
Main-Class: YourMainClass
```

Comment: whats the advantage or the use then of packaing?

Comment: by packaging, you can load jar files into your generated jar via "JarRsrcLoader" class. if you are using 3rd party jars and want to combine your application code with these jars, you can use eclipse's packaging utility like this. see my edited answer.

Comment: Beware of performance issues. I used to package my library jars inside my application jar using jarinjarloader until yesterday. Then, after updating JRE to version 8 update 31 (on windows), executing my application became tremendously slower (up to 10x). The problem was solved when i chose to extract the content of library jars into my jar.

Comment: Surely @Giuseppe that performance hit will only occur as the class is loaded; once the application is running, it should make no difference ....

Comment: @MikeW That is what you would think, but my application was still about an order of magnitude slower the whole time running with "package". Choosing the "extract" option makes the performance much quicker.

Comment: @dminear - that's interesting, I think there are tools you can use to identify bottlenecks in speed - that would certainly be of technical interest ! Perhaps it's cached differently .... but I would have thought experimenting with JVM settings might help identify the reason

Answer (score 5):

For my use, the principal difference is that **packaged** JAR files are included intact as a distinct item, hence retaining their copyright information and signature data.

If you choose **extract**, the class files are pulled out of their original context and stored as if you had originated them, hence possibly violating some licence conditions, although the size of the final JAR will be smaller in this case. Eclipse does warn you about licensing in this case, too.

So, if using third-party JAR libraries, it's professional to always **package**.

Comment: Does convert the project to Maven and then generating the jar will extract or package?

Answer (score 0):

Try it both ways, and open the resulting jar files with a Zip program. Very instructive.

Answer (score 0):

These are mainly two ways to export as a Runnable `jar` in `eclipse`.

**1). Package required libraries into jar**

- This will add actual `jar` files of the libraries into your `jar`.
  This is the cleanest since it separates application class files with
  library JARs.
- The downside is this makes runnable jar perform very slow.

**2). Extract required libraries into generated jar**

- This way will extract only the actual class files from the libraries
  that your application uses and includes in the runnable `jar` file.
  As a result your Jar file will include your application class files
  as well as class files of all the libraries used by your application.
- This method makes runnable jar perform just like it is run in your
  `eclipse` IDE.