# Ant Build Failed in Eclipse

Tags: java, ant

I was building an jar file of my project using ANT after searching in Google  found how do do it i referred [this](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/ant/ant-sample-build-file-jar-1.html) ink. Below is my build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="ExcelData" default="compress">

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" />
    </target>

    <target name="compress" depends="compile">
            <jar destfile="dist/ExcelData.jar" basedir="build/classes" />
    </target>

    <target name="execute" depends="compile">
        <java classname="com.spt.excel.data.ExcelData" classpath="build/classes" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
        <delete dir="dist" />
    </target>

</project>
```

but the problem is the ANT building is failing. But i am getting errors as

```
D:\Eclipse\workspace\ExcelData\src\com\spt\excel\data\ExcelData.java:24: error: package org.slf4j does not exist`
```

And referred [this](http://forums.drftpd.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2978&sid=478d8abc034aafaa05b5dfa880fdbde4) link to set tools.jar.

Can Anyone tell me where i am going wrong. Thank You in advance.

Comment: are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have no include libraries to your ant file, I mean classpath, just add all libs that your eclipse project contains to ant file and all will work, and please read original tutorial like [this one](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

like that

```
<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/lib1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/lib2.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
```

for libs

```
<path id="mylibs">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="mylibs" debug="on"/>
```

add properties lib.dir

```
 <property name="lib.dir"  location="{here is path to your libraries}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Sergii what if we many libraries do we need to include all of those

Comment: @Rithesh update my answer, BTW, try to read docs before write something.

Comment: if we give lib.dir,src.dir its giving error as D:\Eclipse\workspace\ExcelData\${lib.dir} not found.

Answer (score 2):

For Eclipse I recommend following:

```
Right click your project -> Export -> Runnable Jar file 

Pick launch configuration, destination, extract required libraries into JAR, tick Save as ANT script

Finish.
```

Eventually you would have Jar file generated together with reusable Ant script.

Then you analyze your Ant script.

[Difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file)

Comment: hi Nikolay i wanted, by using that build.xml one

Comment: Creating ant files from IDE like extracting and so on, do not provide knowledge how to create real build file, as result questions like that,  I think, just for author, will be perfect to read docs from ant.apache.com and create MANUALLY build file. But your point is good, for solid developers :). Cheers!

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk, if the OP has no experience in Ant, then generating valid Ant script first is the best. And then reading docs for each generated ant task. I personally did it this way. It is time saving :)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Yep, I am agree, it's saving time