# JavaFX Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, javafx, jar

So I made small **JavaFX** project that runs fine in IDE. But when exported in runnable jar in does not run on double click.

In terminal I get following error. I am running **Ubuntu 15.04** on 64bit system.

I already did a lot of google search and installed both **GTK3** and **GTK2** libraries. 
I am aware that this is copy of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s) but I think it is outdated and non of the methods there have helped me.

I tried adding external jars to my project as **gtk.jar**, **swt.jar**, **swt-gtk-java3.8.jar** and installed every possible library like **libswt-gtk-3-java**, **libgtk2.0**, **libgtk2.0-dev**, **libswt-gtk-java-2**, **libgtk-3-dev**, **libgtk-3** and **libswt-gtk-4-java**.

Bellow is detailed error message in terminal using flag `-Dprism.verbose=true`.

```
    Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using java-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/nemanja/amd64/libprism_es2.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.lambda$static$464(ES2Pipeline.java:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:50)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/nemanja/amd64/libprism_sw.so
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:201)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:39)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$472(SWPipeline.java:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(SWPipeline.java:41)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Short version

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: How does your classpath look like when executing and how did you build the executable jar?

Comment: @hotzst To build executable jar,i use Eclipse export project,runnable jar,package required libraries into jar and finish.I am not familiar with class path?

Comment: @hotzst how do i set up class path?

Comment: Take a log at https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm. This should help with creating a executable jar that contains everything.

Comment: @hotzst I think there is some problem with Can't load library: /home/nemanja/amd64/libprism_sw.so`,I have that lib in my JRE installation,but there is no that location in my pc?

Comment: Did you overcome this issue? If yes, could you please add your answer. I got struck into same issue.

Comment: @SamuelAlexander no,was to lazy to do it,but i guess you can solve if you follow hotzst insturctions,but for a fact this would work on Windows my friend tried it and it worked fine,but wont work as executable jar on my Linux system

Answer (score 1):

*What's (probably) going wrong*

> To build executable jar,i use Eclipse export project,runnable jar,package required libraries into jar

Don't use the "package required libraries into jar" to package JavaFX applications.  I am not an Eclipse user, but that sounded like a weird option (standard Java packaging does not include library jar files inside your application jar files).  So I googled what that option is and came up with this:

- [Difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file)

It seems that the option actually does place libraries inside your application jar and creates some kind of custom class loading system in order to use them.

My guess is that you might have added the jfxrt.jar file as a library file in Eclipse and then it is exported and added to your application jar file by the "package required libraries into jar" option.  However jfxrt.jar is not a stand-alone thing, it is not designed to be used outside the directory of the java runtime installation.  jfxrt.jar requires binary files (e.g. .so files on unix or .dll files on windows) that interface to the graphics system of the OS in order for JavaFX to function correctly.  So you really should not be trying to extract it and use it outside of a JRE installation or a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

*Solution*

What you should do instead is to package your application using any of:

- [e(fx)clipse packaging](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/).
- [javafx maven packaging](https://javafx-maven-plugin.github.io).
- [javafx ant packaging or the javapackager tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/part_packaging.html).

Comment: Hmm can you provide more detail how to pack it using javapackager tool,i used command javapackager -makeall -appclass.What shoud be class paramater

Comment: i read the documentation about javapackager but its not clear,What should -appclass paramater be?