# Include external dependencies for executable .jar

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

How can I include a dependency (*`external.jar`*) for an executable jar file?

Comment: why you don't include your jars in your jar ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Go for it!

Comment: without using maven

Comment: yes you can include your jars in your jar

Comment: what IDE you are using eclipse or netbeans or what?

Comment: i want to add dependency without access to the source code

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file

Comment: @HaroonIsmailbasha , yes it was helpful and i think it can solve my problem , but i don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Please Check whether this is helpful..

Right click on project and select Export and then runnable jar file. then use below link and screenshot.

Link for Packaging/Extracting explanation.
 [Difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file)

In Eclipse:

[image: Packaging/Extracting dependencies]